# Getting input from checkboxs and a list

Tags: java, swing, null, jframe, output

Here is the problem i am trying to display what an user has selected in check box and list.

I can successfully display what the user has selected but i am getting a null in front before the display .

Here is the code which i get what user has selected in the check box.

```
String tests=" ";  //declared variable


   if(chkbloodtest.isSelected())
   {
       tests=tests+","+chkbloodtest.getText();
   }


   if(chkurinetest.isSelected())
   {
       tests=tests+","+chkurinetest.getText();
   }
   if(chkngotest.isSelected())
   {
       tests=tests+","+chkngotest.getText();
   }
   if(chkecgtest.isSelected())
   {
       tests=tests+","+chkecgtest.getText();
   }
```

Here is the code where i got what the user has selected in the list.

```
String treatments=lsttreatments.getSelectedValuesList().toString();
```

Here is the out put i get :-

[image]

What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: You're not showing us enough to know 100% what is causing your problem. Perhaps you're re-declaring the tests variable? Who knows and most of us are bad at guessing. You will want to do debugging to first isolate your problem -- use intermediate println statements, to find out *where* the null is coming from.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Thanks man you are correct i have again reinitialized the test and treatment variable inside a constructor which i passed the values in to. I managed to fix it now.

Thanks alot.

Comment: @Shehan.W: I'm glad you've solved it, but next time, please strive to write your question so that we don't have to make lucky guesses to answer it. You should ask your question with a mind-set of, "what would a volunteer need to know to fully understand my problem?".